# UIView Animations seem to speed up after first time, Xcode 6.1 swift

Tags: xcode, swift, uiviewanimation

For some reason after my first call of a serious of animation blocks, the animation seems to be faster, not sure if this is a bug or something i've done wrong but i'm sure someone call tell me.. i've made a UIView subclass to handle this.

```
import UIKit
import QuartzCore

class GBPopupController: UIView {

var originalContainerCenterY = CGFloat()

@IBOutlet var continerConstraintCenterY: NSLayoutConstraint!
@IBOutlet var containerConstraintCenterX: NSLayoutConstraint!


var startingCenter = CGPoint()
@IBOutlet var contentView: UIView!
@IBOutlet var button: UIButton!


override func layoutSubviews() {
    super.layoutSubviews()
    contentView.layer.cornerRadius = 10
    button.layer.cornerRadius = 10

}

override func didMoveToSuperview() {
   self.beginViewAnimations()
}

func animatePopupIn() {

    UIView.animateWithDuration(1.0, delay: 0.0, usingSpringWithDamping: 0.6, initialSpringVelocity: 0.7, options: UIViewAnimationOptions.CurveEaseIn, animations: {

        self.contentView.layer.transform = CATransform3DIdentity

        }, completion: {finished in
    })
}

func beginViewAnimations() {
    var transform = CATransform3DIdentity;
    transform = CATransform3DMakeTranslation(0, -self.frame.size.height, 0)

    self.contentView.layer.transform = transform

    UIView.animateWithDuration(0.4, delay: 0.0, options: UIViewAnimationOptions.TransitionCrossDissolve, animations: {

        self.backgroundColor = UIColor(white: 0.0, alpha: 0.5)

        }, completion: {finished in

            self.animatePopupIn()
    })


}

func removeViewFromSuperView() {
    UIView.animateWithDuration(0.5, delay: 0.0, options: UIViewAnimationOptions.TransitionCrossDissolve, animations: {

        var transform = CATransform3DIdentity;
        transform = CATransform3DMakeTranslation(0, -self.frame.size.height, 0)
        self.contentView.layer.transform = transform

        }, completion: {finished in

            UIView.animateWithDuration(0.4, delay: 0.0, options: UIViewAnimationOptions.TransitionCrossDissolve, animations: {
                self.backgroundColor = UIColor.clearColor()

                }, completion: {finished in
                    self.removeViewAnimation()
            })

    })
}

func removeViewAnimation() {
    self.removeFromSuperview()

}
```

Comment: I might have the same kind of problem. I have a button that open/close a view. I used UIView.animateWithDuration(0.5, animations: {}) and I don't know why but the first time I open the view with this method the animation is different. Did you find an answer?

Comment: Nope, didn't find an answer unfortunately

Answer (score 0):

My comment is too long so I answer here. I don't know if it can help you but here's what I did.

I use autolayout and so in the viewdidload(), dimensions are not yet initialized. They are based on a 600x600 size screen (meaning any width, any height). Screen size is picked up once the first action is done (like pushing a button in my case).

This is why I call my animation for the first time at this first action, just to put my frame at the good place. Then the rest is the same. But it kind of initialize my view with the right frame (size and position). After that, I don't have this problem and my animation is also good.

It's like I was calling it twice the first time, one to initialize and one just to play the animation.

I made some research and I found that it could be a problem with the layer which is different from the frame and which is initialized with a different animation from the one you choose. That's why I didn't have the same animation the first time.

Hope it will help you.